# Returning a second value through pointer or reference C++

Tags: c++, string, pointers

I already searched, and couldn't find anything exactly like this one.  Although there do seem to be similarities.  If a mod or admin thinks this is a duplicate topic, please let me know which one and ask me how I think it might be different before you delete it.

If I'm returning an int value in a function, how do I return a second one indirectly with a pointer or reference parameter?  I have a practice problem I need to do that is asking for this:

> Write a function that takes two input arguments and provides two
>   separate results to the caller, one that is the result of multiplying
>   the two arguments, the other the result of adding them. Since you can
>   directly return only one value from a function, you'll need the second
>   value to be returned through a pointer or reference parameter.

And I also need to return a string pointer through a function.

> 1. Write a function that prompts the user to enter his or her first name and last name, as two separate values. This function should
>      return both values to the caller via additional pointer (or reference)
>      parameters that are passed to the function. Try doing this first with
>      pointers and then with references.

I already did this one with a reference to a pointer, but I'm having trouble doing it with pointers.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string userName(string user_first_name, string user_last_name);

int main()
{
    string user_first_name;
    string user_last_name;
    cout << "Program for taking in user's full name\n";
    cout << userName(user_first_name, user_last_name);
}

string userName(string user_first_name, string user_last_name)
{
    cout << "Please provide your first name: ";
    cin >> user_first_name;
    cout << "Please provide your last name: ";
    cin >> user_last_name;
    string full_name = user_first_name + " " + user_last_name;
    return full_name;
}
```

Whenever I try to use those string variables as pointers, I get an error saying I can't convert a string to a string*, or I get an error saying I can't convert a string* to a string**.

As for the other one, this is the code I have:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int* pointerMath();

int main()
{
    cout << "Let's do some math!\n";
    pointerMath();
}

int* pointerMath()
{
    int value1;
    int value2;
    cout << "Provide the first number: ";
    cin >> value1;
    cout << "Provide the second number: ";
    cin >> value2;
    int *multiplication_result = value1 * value2;
    int *addition_result = value1 + value2;
    cout << "The numbers added together are: " << *addition_result << '\n';
    cout << "The numbers multiplied by each other are: " << *multiplication_result << '\n';
    return multiplication_result;
 }
```

Whenever I run this, it always crashes right after getting both input values, and I get an error code 255.

Edit:

I also have to further modify the string name program, per this question's specification:

> 3. Modify the program you wrote for exercise 1 so that instead of always prompting the user for a last name, it does so only if the
>      caller passes in a NULL pointer for the last name.

How do I do this?

Comment: have you googled "reference parameter"? It's an **extremely** common pattern.

Comment: Which anomalies did you experience, when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: it is not clear from the yellow part that you need the fullname returned.

Comment: btw my answer tackles the multiplication problem too.

Comment: Note: I have just edited my original post here to add something in.  Please look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it with pointers, you have to introduce *pointers*, i.e.

Change this:

> ```
>  string userName(string user_first_name, string user_last_name);
> ```

to that (note `string*` for pointer parameters):

```
string userName(string* user_first_name, string* user_last_name);
```

Moreover, when you sue `cin` you have to dereference the pointer, using the `(*pointer)` syntax, e.g.:

```
string userName(string* user_first_name, string* user_last_name)
{
    cout << "Please provide your first name: ";
    cin >> (*user_first_name); // <-- dereference pointer
    cout << "Please provide your last name: ";
    cin >> (*user_last_name);  // <-- dereference pointer
    string full_name = (*user_first_name) + " " + (*user_last_name);
    return full_name;
}
```

And in `main()`, you should pass the address of the variables using the address-of `&` operator:

```
int main()
{
    string user_first_name;
    string user_last_name;
    cout << "Program for taking in user's full name\n";

    // Use & to get address of (pointers) to first and last name
    cout << userName(&user_first_name, &user_last_name);
}
```

Now that I showed you some sample code, you should be able to use a similar coding pattern for the other case.

Comment: I need to return a string pointer, though, for that program with the name function.  Will it really return a string pointer if I just make the variables passed into it string pointers?

Answer (score 1):

> > Since you can directly return only one value from a function, you'll
> >     need the second value to be returned through a pointer or reference
> >     parameter.

This is extremely **misleading**. It's true that you can technically only return one value, but nothing stops you from returning a custom type that internally holds two values. This approach is usually superior to references or out pointers and should be the default choice:

```
struct Value
{
    int x;
    int y;
};

Value GetValue()
{
    return { 1, 2 };
}
```

> I already did this one with a reference to a pointer, but I'm having
>   trouble doing it with pointers.

You should not do it with a pointer in the first place. Not with a pointer directly and not with a reference to a pointer. A reference would suffice.

> ```
>  string userName(string user_first_name, string user_last_name);
> ```

These string parameters are copies. The function will operate on copies of the arguments, and the original strings on the outside will be left untouched.

> Whenever I try to use those string variables as pointers, I get an
>   error saying I can't convert a string to a string*, or I get an error
>   saying I can't convert a string* to a string**.

Because a pointer to something is not implicitly convertible to something, and vice versa (this is also true if "something" is itself a pointer).

Just use references:

```
string userName(string& user_first_name, string& user_last_name);
```

> ```
> int *multiplication_result = value1 * value2;
> ```

The result of `value1 * value2` is an `int`. You cannot just take an `int` and use it as if it was a pointer. Your code should not even compile but fail with an error message like `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int *'`, unless you are using an ancient compiler or invoke it with the wrong settings.

Comment: `std::pair` is usually my preference for returning two things, rather than creating an ad hoc class. But ymmv.

Comment: @rici: Yes, it depends on what the return value really represents. It could also be an `std::tuple`, or even something like an `std::array` or an `std::vector`. The point is that it's always *technically* one return value but *practically* more than that.

Comment: @OsmanZakir: `include <utility>` and then use `std::pair` with the two types you need, in your case `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`.

Comment: I need it for the addition and multiplication one, though, where I have to return one value directly and the second one indirectly as a pointer or a reference.  How should I do a return with this? Initialize the pair with int types and then type parentheses and put in the two variables I want to return?

Comment: I wanted to try something like this: return pair<int, int> (addition_result, multiplication_result);  But it's not working. What's the correct way?

Comment: @OsmanZakir: "it's not working" is not exactly a very precise error description! :) The code is correct, although `return std::make_pair(addition_result, multiplication_result)` would be even more concise.

Comment: @OsmanZakir: Here is an ultra-short example of `std::pair` usage: `std::pair<int, int> f() { return std::make_pair(1, 1); } int main() { std::pair<int, int> result = f(); }`

Comment: I did this: return pair<int, int*> (addition_result, multiplication_result); and I got the following error and warning (note: I've included the <utility> header file): 28|error: cannot convert 'std::pair<int, int*>' to 'int*' in return| and |29|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|  This is what I mean by "not working"

Comment: Do I have to change the return type of the function?  If so, then, to what do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, you need use `&` to pass your string value. I think it's better to understand than using passing pointer.
also you can pass the pointer like this:
    #include

```
using namespace std;

string *userName(string user_first_name, string user_last_name);

int main()
{
    string user_first_name;
    string user_last_name;
    cout << "Program for taking in user's full name\n";
    cout << *(userName(user_first_name, user_last_name));
}

string* userName(string user_first_name, string user_last_name)
{
   cout << "Please provide your first name: ";
   cin >> user_first_name;
   cout << "Please provide your last name: ";
   cin >> user_last_name;
   string *full_name = new string;
   *full_name = user_first_name + " " + user_last_name;
   return full_name;
}
```

int *multiplication_result is a pointer, it need to be bind with a value. after that you can make it point to a int value.
you can pass the value by this way:

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
int* pointerMath();

int main()
{
    cout << "Let's do some math!\n";
    cout<<*(pointerMath()) <<endl;
}

int* pointerMath()
{
   int value1;
   int value2;
   cout << "Provide the first number: ";
   cin >> value1;
   cout << "Provide the second number: ";
   cin >> value2;
   int *multiplication_result = new int;
   *multiplication_result = value1 * value2;
   int addition_result = value1 + value2;
   cout << "The numbers added together are: " << addition_result << '\n';
   cout << "The numbers multiplied by each other are: " << *multiplication_result << '\n';
   return multiplication_result;
 }
```

Comment: I need to return two values in this one, one directly and one as a pointer or reference.  The code you gave there returns the pointer directly, but I need to return a normal int variable directly and give back a pointer or reference to main() indirectly somehow, which is what I don't get how to do.

Comment: pass one value by return, another one by `&param` ?

Comment: and how do I implement this one? "Modify the program you wrote for exercise 1 so that instead of always prompting the user for a last
name, it does so only if the caller passes in a NULL pointer for the last name."

Answer (score 0):

> Write a function that takes two input arguments and provides two
>   separate results to the caller, one that is the result of multiplying
>   the two arguments, the other the result of adding them. Since you can
>   directly return only one value from a function, you'll need the second
>   value to be returned through a pointer or reference parameter.

```
int multiplyAndAdd(int a, int b, int& sum){
    sum = a+b;
    return a*b;
}
```

calling this is like this :

```
int sum=0;
int multiply = multiplyAndAdd(2,3,sum);
```

I am in favor of using a reference instead of a pointer. In the latter case it would be like this :

```
int multiplyAndAdd(int a, int b, int* sum){
    *sum = a+b; //--> probably a null check is needed
    return a*b;
}
```

and then calling like this :

```
int sum=0;
int multiply = multiplyAndAdd(2,3,&sum);
```

the string exercise is almost the same:
with references:

```
void returnstrings(string& s1, string& s2){
   //whatever here you just assign s1 and s2
}
```

calling it :

```
string firstName;
string lastName;
returnstrings(firstName,lastName);
```

with pointers :

```
void returnstrings(string* s1, string* s2){
   //whatever here you just assign *s1 and *s2
}
```

calling it :

```
string firstName;
string lastName;
returnstrings(&firstName,&lastName);
```